# Error starting Springboot when update version to 2.7.0 "An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist"

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

**I updated Springboot version to 2.7.0, and after return me errors:**

Description:

```
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator.scanForWebJars(WebJarAssetLocator.java:183)

The following method did not exist:

    'io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph.acceptPaths(java.lang.String[])'

The calling method's class, org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/home/gabriel/.m2/repository/org/webjars/webjars-locator-core/0.50/webjars-locator-core-0.50.jar!/org/webjars/WebJarAssetLocator.class

The called method's class, io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/home/gabriel/.m2/repository/io/github/classgraph/classgraph/4.8.69/classgraph-4.8.69.jar!/io/github/classgraph/ClassGraph.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph: file:/home/gabriel/.m2/repository/io/github/classgraph/classgraph/4.8.69/classgraph-4.8.69.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator and io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph
```

**This is my pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>re.brasuka</groupId>
    <artifactId>bra</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gto</name>
    <description>Projeto do BRASUKA</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Lib para Serealizar e Desserealizar Json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Lib para acesso a servidor SFTP-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.55</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Lib para converte arquivo em objeto -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.univocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>univocity-parsers</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Documentação -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.8</version>
        </dependency>
        

        <!-- Registri e Gateway -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Client FTP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Criação de Json para retornos -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20201115</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Para gerar PDF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Starter do Spring para envio de email -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Can i fix this?

Answer (score 43):

There's an incompatibility in the transitive dependencies of `org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui`. It depends on both `org.webjars:webjars-core-locator` and `io.github.classgraph:classgraph` but their versions are incompatible.

Spring Boot's dependency management for `webjars-core-locator` uses version `0.50`. `webjars-core-locator` `0.50` would use `classgraph` `4.8.139` by default but, due to the way that Maven resolves version conflicts, it's being downgraded to `4.8.69`.

You can fix the problem by restoring the use of `4.8.139` by adding some dependency management to your `pom.xml` alongside your existing import of `spring-cloud-dependencies`:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.classgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>classgraph</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.139</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Thank you. After upgrading from Spring Boot 2.6 -> 2.7 I encountered this same problem and with your solution, my tests finished OK again.

Answer (score 16):

Adding the following implementation to the build.gradle file also fixes the issue:
implementation('org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.9')

Comment: Using org.springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.9 fixed the issue

Answer (score 13):

As stated in the other answers, it is indeed springdoc-openapi-ui making trouble here. I had various errors regarding WebJarAssetLocator and/or ClassGraph, which both resolved by also updating springdoc.

Now, with spring-boot 2.7.2 and spring-doc 1.6.9, everything runs smoothly again.

Comment: Seems to have reappeared with 2.7.3. As suggested by @Andy Wilkinson, adding the io.github.classgraph portion of his solution to the the dependency management section of the pom.xml fixes it.

Answer (score 7):

I have fixed with upgrading springdoc-openapi-ui to 1.6.12

Answer (score 3):

Just adding my ¢2 with some code sample.
I upgraded an existing project to Spring boot 2.7.5 and received a similar  "warning" as

```
"level":"WARN","thread":"main","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext","message":"Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
....
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph.acceptPaths(java.lang.String[])'","context":"default"}
```

and prevented the app from starting.

I updated `org.springdoc` version to the latest as in this page and it fixed the error. https://springdoc.org/#spring-webflux-support

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.12</version>
</dependency>
```