# What use does Spring data jpa gives to classgraph dependency? Conflict between dependencies with Springdoc

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa, springdoc-openapi-ui

I had a dependencies problem between Spring data jpa 2.7.2 and springdoc-openapi-ui 1.6.3, the conflicting dependency is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.classgraph</groupId>
  <artifactId>classgraph</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I have never seen this artifact so im not sure what is the use they are giving to it (maybe they are using this to map important annotations like @Transactional?), in consequence Im not sure if the solution I am giving its not going to cause any trouble, anyways heres the details:

Spring data jpa uses the version 4.8.108
Springdoc uses version 4.8.117

*Spring data*: [image]

**Springdoc**: [image]

**The solution**:

First, exclude the dependency on both artifacts:

Springdata:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>io.github.classgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>classgraph</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Springdoc:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.github.classgraph</groupId>
                <artifactId>classgraph</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Second and lastly, add the dependency (I chose this version cause another project that had this problem is using this one too):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.classgraph</groupId>
    <artifactId>classgraph</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.147</version>
</dependency>
```

So far no problems, but I hate not really knowing what is going on behind the scenes with this artifact (what use it has for spring data jpa? and as a plus maybe you could tell me the use for springdoc), and I just chose this version because I saw it was being used in another project with the same problem...

Lastly here is the most similar situation I could fine here at SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/72403827/12085680