# Correct the classpath of your app so that it contains compat. vers. of the classes org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator and io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, swagger

I find it difficult to fix the problem. Would you please helping me out?
Console output:

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-03-14T13:24:39.051+05:00 ERROR 19984 --- [cms] [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator.scanForWebJars(WebJarAssetLocator.java:188)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
'io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph.acceptPaths(java.lang.String[])'
```

The calling method's class, org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator, was loaded from the following location:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/Valentin/.m2/repository/org/webjars/webjars-locator-core/0.55/webjars-locator-core-0.55.jar!/org/webjars/WebJarAssetLocator.class
```

The called method's class, io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/Valentin/.m2/repository/io/github/classgraph/classgraph/4.8.69/classgraph-4.8.69.jar!/io/github/classgraph/ClassGraph.class
```

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph: file:/C:/Users/Valentin/.m2/repository/io/github/classgraph/classgraph/4.8.69/classgraph-4.8.69.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator and io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph

Process finished with exit code 1

I suppose that the issue is with pom.xml file:

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.2.3
 

ru.aston.crm
cms
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
cms
Customer Management Service

<java.version>17</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger/swagger-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Although I'm investigating the problem carefully, I have no idea, where to start.

Comment: you can resolve issue using this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72403827/1107405